# Python Split only take the 3 array

Tags: python

Im making some script to separate between two array using `|` and im testing it using two line of

```
email1|password1
email2|password2
```

it only giving me the

```
password1
email2|password2
```

i have tried to use one line of it but it giving me `IndexError: list index out of range`

the spliting script

```
import sys

maillist = sys.argv[1]
email = open(maillist, 'r').read().split('|')
print(email[1]+'|'+email[2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the real problem you have right now is that you may not know Pyhon starts counting at 0 instead of 1. As for a full solution to the problem I will refer you to Jab's answer.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for pull me out from this confusing

Comment: @Limited don't forget to upvote answers you found useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like:

```
email1|password1
email2|password2
```

And you split by '|' then you will get 3 values returned, the first email, then the first password and the second email as one item, then the second password. That’s why when you access the second and third items you’re only missing the first email. You either need to `.split()` then `.split('|')` to remove that line or loop through each line.

```
import sys

maillist = sys.argv[1]
with open(maillist, 'r') as email:
    for line in email:
        email, pass = line.split('|')
        print(email, '|', pass)
```